# Fewer bags but overweight

Tags: luggage

3 family members including one kid are traveling to Qatar from the US with 4 pieces of luggage, but the weight exceeds 23 kg. Is there a pooling system? Will the airline allow us to take a 28-kg bag without charging us? We are flying in economy class.

Comment: Most airlines allow one piece of baggage per person, to a maximum weight per person, but you have an extra item. Consider whether you really do need to take so much stuff.

Comment: Which airline, travelling from where? Baggage rules vary a lot.

Comment: What does the airline website say about excess baggage fees?

Comment: If you're asking whether you can pool your allowances: One of the reasons behind the weight limits are the working conditions of the handlers, and those don't care about the total (the handlers move tons of luggage every day, so the total is meaningless), so no, you can't pool your allowances, every bag has to be under 23 kg. (If you don't want to pay)

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity in many (most?) cases this is not actually true. There is a hard limit usually at 30 kg, but you can often pool weights of all luggage and have heavier bags than the allowance as long as you stay under the hard limit. But this depends A LOT on the airline and the specific route.

Comment: With most airlines I used over the last years, luggage pooling only referred to uneven distribution of weight between the bags (e.g. 26 + 20 instead of the stated 23 + 23), but not to bringing a larger number of bags. If I understand your question correctly, you have more bags than people travelling, which is not covered by any luggage pooling policy if one piece per person is allowed.

Comment: Are you saying that the combined weight of the four items is over 23 kg?  What is the luggage policy on your tickets?

Answer (score 3):

That depends a lot on the airline and sometimes even on the individual check in agent.  Most airlines these days use bag fees as a significant part of their revenue so they are unlikely to accommodate you, if there is a chance to charge you instead.

This being said, we also had airline that did allow taking more bags then allowed as long as the pile was inside the total weight allowance.

Airlines do have strict weight limits in individual pieces which for most airlines is 23 kg in economy. The will will charge a lot for a 28 kg bag regardless of any other bag. For most airlines you can look up the charges in their website.